# Java anagram recursion List<List<String>> only storing empty lists<Strings>

Tags: java, recursion

Hi In this recursion method i am trying to find all anagrams and add it to a List> but what happens when i run this code is it just returns alot of empty Lists.

```
      private List<List<String>> findAnagrams(LetterInventory words,
        ArrayList<String> anagram, int max,
        Map<String, LetterInventory> smallDict, int level, List<List<String>> result) {

    ArrayList<String> solvedWord = new ArrayList<String>();
    LetterInventory shell;
    LetterInventory shell2;
    if (level < max || max == 0) {
        Iterator<String> it = smallDict.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String k = it.next();
            shell = new LetterInventory(k);
            shell2 = words;
            if (shell2.subtract(shell) != null) {
                anagram.add(k);
                shell2 = words.subtract(shell);
                if (shell2.isEmpty()) {
                    //System.out.println(anagram.toString()); it prints off fine here
                                            result.add(anagram); // but doesnt add here

                }
                else 

                    findAnagrams(shell2, anagram, max, smallDict, level + 1, result);
                anagram.remove(anagram.size()-1);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug? Sounds like problem with  `if (shell2.subtract(shell) != null) {`. Can you give inputs for above mentioned method

Comment: well basicly LetterInventory stores the numbers of each char of a word and the subtract method in that will return null if the result of numbers of char of one word minus the other is negative basically that char is not in that word

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it's here.

```
else 
    findAnagrams(shell2, anagram, max, smallDict, level + 1, result);
anagram.remove(anagram.size()-1);  // this is outside of the else case
```

You remove an element from `anagram` every time you add it.  Did you mean to for it to be in the `else`?

```
else {
    findAnagrams(shell2, anagram, max, smallDict, level + 1, result);
    anagram.remove(anagram.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: suppose yes, :) pretty famous mistake. For that reason its good practice to add braces no matter one row of code or more

Comment: ah na its not that im was doing a sysout print to see what was going on and its prints the list of Strings fine but it doesn't get added to the list of list though.. which has me just confused